# Creating premake project for PuTTYTray

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2013, premake

I'm trying to use Premake 4 to create VS2013 project files for [PuTTYTray](https://github.com/FauxFaux/PuTTYTray).

Initially I'm trying to build just putty.exe but I'd like to be able to build the original suite, based on the original project files.

```
solution "PuTTYTray"
configurations {"Debug", "Release"}

    project "PuTTY"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        language "C++"

        files { 
            "*.h", 
            "*.c",
            "windows/**.c", 
            "windows/**.h" 
        }

        excludes {
            "pscp.c", 
            "be_all.c", 
            "psftp.c", 
            "be_all_u.c", 
            "be_none.c",
            "be_nos*",
            "be_ssh.c",
            "nocproxy.c",
            "puttytel*",
            "notiming.c",
            "noterm.c",
            "noprint.c",
            "noshare.c",
            "pproxy.c",
            "windows/wincons.c",
            "cmdgen.c",
            "time.c",
            "windows/winnojmp.c",
            "windows/winplink.c",
            "windows/winsftp.c",

        }

        defines {
            "_WINDOWS", 
            "NO_GSSAPI", 
            "WIN32", 
            "SECURITY_WIN32",
            "_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES=1",
            "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1"
        }

        links {
            "advapi32",
            "comctl32",
            "imm32",
            "winmm"
        }

        includedirs {"windows","unix","."}
```

I believe I have the config set up similarly to the original but I get the following errors:

```
Error   34  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'termios.h': No such file or directory   D:\Git\Other\PuTTYTray\windows\cthelper\ptyfork.c   2   1   PuTTY
Error   15  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory    D:\Git\Other\PuTTYTray\windows\cthelper\buffer.c    4   1   PuTTY
Error   16  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory    D:\Git\Other\PuTTYTray\windows\cthelper\cthelper.c  4   1   PuTTY
Error   17  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory    d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\ourhdr.h    10  1   PuTTY
Error   35  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory    d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\ourhdr.h    10  1   PuTTY
Error   22  error C2059: syntax error : ')' d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\mm.h    7   1   PuTTY
...
Error   19  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'len'    d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\mm.h    7   1   PuTTY
Error   30  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'len'    d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\mm.h    10  1   PuTTY
Error   24  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'nmemb'  d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\mm.h    9   1   PuTTY
Error   29  error C2081: 'ssize_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal  d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\mm.h    10  1   PuTTY
Error   18  error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'len' d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\mm.h    7   1   PuTTY
Error   28  error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'len' d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\mm.h    10  1   PuTTY
Error   23  error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'nmemb'   d:\git\other\puttytray\windows\cthelper\mm.h    9   1   PuTTY
```

What can I do to get closer to the mark? I'm not really understanding what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Do those header files exist? Are they on a path that is available to the compiler?

Comment: As far as I can tell they're not, but the project owner is building for Windows without them. I'm trying to get a hold of his original nmake Makefile now

Comment: The `termios.h` and `unistd.h` files are specific to linux...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I didn't have the correct list of excludes - the original project files can be generated by running a perl script in the root of the source.

With the correct excludes and some extra library imports I can create and use the solution successfully.

@ostrokarch's note pointed me in the right direction here.